# Is there any property need to set-up to allow the double-tap (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I can not detect the double-tap in screen? Do i need to turn on the property in the project?

So i try this, but it doesn't work:

```
let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

tapRec.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameScene.doubleTap))
tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)



@objc func doubleTap(){
   print ("tap")
}
```

Comment: Check `self.view` user interaction.

Comment: Where are you writing this code in? `GameScene`?

Comment: `view.userInteractionEnabled = true` try this

Comment: @Sweeper hi yes. In the GameScene.

Comment: @KaushikMakwana Hi. Still not working :(

Comment: `tapRec.delegate = self` try this

Comment: @KaushikMakwana what is tapGR meaning?

Comment: sorry its typos, updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a double tap Gesture Recognizer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262795/how-to-add-a-double-tap-gesture-recognizer-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap(_:)))
tapRec.delegate = self
tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
view.userInteractionEnabled = true
view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
```

And then your function:

```
extension YourViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func handleDoubleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("doubletapped")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thank @OkiRules

No it isn't. 

And i can not add the extension in the GameScene file, it shows an error: Declaration is only valid at file scope

Comment: Hi! It's working now. I write another function inside the GameViewController so it override the one in GameScene :) Thank you for your help!